# How would I figure out many Groups have Customers with different countries

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to figure out if a scenario exists where we have groups with customers that have different countries. I have a attribute Group that has Customers under it and each customer has a country. I want to count the number of Groups that have customers with different countries in the group.

```
Select 
   Group, 
   count(*) 
from Table 
where Customer IN (select Customer 
                   from Table 
                   where count(country) > 1) 
order by  Group
```

Comment: what's the expected result? You said you want to count the number of groups but that isn't what you would return based on your query. You'll use `HAVING` for this, though.

Comment: I would like to see the group name and a count of how many customers have different countries next to it. I only want the group names that the customer in the group have a different country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, just change the `IN` clause and count on the `Customer`, at least that makes sense to me. You can also use `EXISTS` in a similar fashion.

```
Select 
   Group, 
   CustomerCount = count(distinct Customer) 
from Table 
where Customer IN (select Customer 
                   from Table 
                   group by Customer
                   having count(country) > 1) 
order by  Group
```